# Call login function of passport in socket.io event

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, passport.js

I try to realize a login via websocket in socket.io using passport. I searched the whole web for a solution but can't figure out how I can login a websocket with passport.

The idea is that the client side emits an event `login` with username and password as data. The server should then do the login in the `socket.on('login', function(data) ...)` part.

I can emit the event on client side and also react on it on server side. But I can't figure out how I can use my local strategy I defined for passport to login the user with the data I get from client. I managed to perform a login with a separate post request but not via websocket.

So this is the code which emits the `login` event on client side:

```
<script>
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var formData = {};

        $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function() {
            formData[this.name] = this.value;
        });

        socket.emit('login', formData);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

And on server side I have this code which should log me in:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('login', function(loginData) {
        // ----> passport.login based on loginData
    });
});
```

I have connected passport to socket.io useing the `passport.socketio` package and connected the express-session with package `express-socket.io-session`. So the session path works fine far.

Comment: why do you want to do that? I'd suggest use `post` to handle the login and use `passport.socketio` for authenticating the rest of socket's traffic. Passport uses http requests to authenticate while socket.io uses the connection. So I don't think it'd possible (or be a good idea) to use the same logic for both.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ thx for your comment. My idea is that I don't have to mix AJAX calls and websockets but do all the "async" requests over my existing websocket connection instead of firing XHR requests while my websocket connection is idling.